# tracking down Unknown on line 0 errors

Tags: php

From the Apache error logs:

> [Mon Dec 03 14:58:01 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 884830 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: https://www.domain.tld/referer

Why is it saying "Unknown on line 0"?   Why not "Filename.php on line xx"?

Comment: I'll put my money on `PDO` and `SELECT *`, since we have to guess.

Comment: I'm not asking what's causing the error. What I'm asking is why the error - as it's being presented - isn't giving a file name or a line number.

Comment: To those voting to close on the basis that this question is to localized... https://www.google.com/#q=%22Unknown+on+line+0%22&oq=%22 252 million results. A lot of people seem to be having nondescript errors like this.

Comment: @neubert because it's being caused by something outside of your script. PeeHaa is likely spot on with it being an extension. My guess is because the amount being allocated is quite large (kind of like a new result set)

Comment: @neubert And the cause of these errors is potentially infinite. It ***is*** too localised, without specifics. There is no **one** thing that causes this. "*What is the problem?*" gives 5.5 billion results on google. Lots of people have that one too.

Comment: I have encountered the same error message myself today and it turned out to be the line `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");`.  Remove that line and the script works, add it back in and the error returns. The response was about 6.5MB in size without compression and has recently been growing which I think caused the error to happen now.  Maybe your error message is being caused by same problem.

Comment: The logic for closing this as "too localized" is insane. People are arguing that *because the OP didn't just dump reams of his code* and instead asked for how to locate the code causing the error - i.e. the problem that literally everybody who ever sees this error message will immediately have to deal with - the question deserves closure for being insufficiently general? That's crazy and incoherent reasoning. There's a great opportunity for a valuable debugging resource here, blocked off by people who think anything but a "fix my code for me" question with a code dump shouldn't be allowed. :(